# Javascript variable inside mysql query in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, pug

I want to pass a javascript variable inside a MySQL query, however, when i run the query in console.log, but two "\" appears, because of which the code doesn't work.

App.js code

```
    app.get('/home', function(req, res){
     db.connect(function(err){
      var sale = req.query.cbosale;
       db.query("SELECT Year, Season FROM tsales WHERE Sale LIKE '"+sale+"'", function(err, result, fields){
        res.render('home', {title:"home",data:result});
      })
     })
   })
```

In console.log it shows the query as:-

```
    SELECT Year, Season FROM tsales WHERE Sale LIKE \'13\'
```

The "\" symbols prevent the query from executing. Can you help me out, i am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `/` like this,

```
var formatSaleValue = sale.replace(/\\/g,''));
```

And you can use the formatted value as,

```
db.query("SELECT Year, Season FROM tsales WHERE Sale LIKE '"+formatSaleValue+"'", function(err, result, fields){ ....
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you try, `sale.replace(/\\/g,''));` ? Forgot that it is express.js :-)

Comment: Are you declaring it as a javascript var and then using it in your `db.query...` statement right?

Comment: yes, declaring it as a javascript var. I tried with a static no, strange thing, the query is same but it runs, when i insert the variable, it doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```js
connection.query('SELECT Year, Season FROM tsales WHERE Sale ?', '%' + value + '%', ...)
```

it does escape the single quote, that the problem, you can also try something like this

```
LIKE " + connection.escape('%'+you var+'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the JavaScript var in `'"+ variable +"'`
for example to select a row from a table based on the column id  you have to wrap the JavaScript var in `'"+ variable +"'`
ex: we want to get user info (username, gender, email ...) all his info from the table and we have his id so we do like this:

```
var userid = 8;    
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '"+ userid +"' "
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually doing it this way, hope it helps!

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res){
    db.connect(function(err){
        const sale = req.query.cbosale;
        const dbquery = "SELECT Year, Season FROM tsales WHERE Sale LIKE ?"
        db.query(dbquery, sale, function(err, result, fields){
            res.render('home', {title:"home",data:result});
        })
    })
})
```